Adjusting Dimmer with no visible low end trim
When the dimmer is too low, the lights don't turn on with the flip of the switch until I raise the dimmer and then I can lower it again to make the lights dim.
One thing I read that might be the issue is the low-end trim on the dimmer. After removing the panel, I don't see any adjustment slider.
Is there another way to adjust this Lutron dimmer switch?
What else could be the issue?
Thank you



It might be possible to take apart the dimmer and put a resistor in parallel with a potentiometer to act as a trimmer. That said, it requires some technical knowledge and skill.

@DrMoishePippik that's some wildly inadvisable advice. Pretty sure it voids the UL listing when you start user modifications. Marc J - you'll need to switch off the breaker (or breakers) serving this box and pull out the dimmer to get the actual model number off it (which I don't see on the front of it) and consult Lutron's documentation for that particular model.

@Ecnerwal, yes, it would void any warranty. Yet, I've done so, myself.

Warranty? Ha, no, that's the least of it. It voids your insurance when the formerly UL-listed modified object shows up in the fire investigation, and you get paid nothing to replace your house that you thought was insured.

Here's the "not at all obvious" adjustment for one model, but without knowing your model, hard to  say if it applies to what you have: https://assets.lutron.com/a/documents/048703.pdf#page=13

@DrMoishePippik could you be specific what resistor

@Traveler, as stated, this "requires some technical knowledge and skill." One would have to determine the schematic and the needed value of the resistor, partly by experiment. And as stated  by others, one not knowledgeable and careful could make this a safety hazard.

@DrMoishePippik that is a typical hysteric reaction from people who do not understand anything about electricity. You can not burn your house with modified dimmer circuit. At worst it will trigger the breaker

I have a half dozen of those dimmers in my house and have installed hundreds and they all do that. I never gave it a second thought. Bulbs need a certain amount of voltage/current to turn on. Once they are on, those values can be changed, be lowered, to dim the bulbs. If you turn off the switch when the bulbs are dimmed, and then turn it back on, depending on how dim the lights were, the dimmed voltage/current might not be enough to light the bulb. You'll need to raise the dimmer until the required voltage/current to light the bulb is there. It seems to be more noticable with LED bulbs. It's kind of like the starting current for a motor. They need a certain surge to start up the circuit but it is then reduced.

Similar dimmer switches in my house do same.  +1 on LEDs being more noticeable.  I find I can get a less bright output by going up to middle and backing off than I can only going up from all the way down.  If I only try going up from the bottom, the dimmest it starts is still pretty bright.

Without a trim adjustment, the low and high ends of the dimmer are static. You could read the specifications to find low end and then replace the total bulb wattage to match.
